# Creating excerpt using Javascript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to make excerpt of all **h3** text with some manner using some array methods. But the problem is to select all **h3** I used as selector is

```
var productTitle = $('#products-carousel').find('.single-trending-list').find('h3').text();
```

And it grabs all **h3** texts together and finally I get same text for all **h3**

How can I select all **h3** individually?

Here is [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Jim_Fahad/8s3Lturh/?utm_source=website&utm_medium=embed&utm_campaign=8s3Lturh)

Here is my Code:

```js
var productTitle = $('#products-carousel').find('.single-trending-list').find('h3').text(),
 productTitleExcerpt;
 var toArray = productTitle.split("", 36),
 joinArray = toArray.join(''),
 joinArrayToArray = joinArray.split(" "),
 joinArrayToArrayPop = joinArrayToArray.pop(),
 joinArrayToArrayPopPush = joinArrayToArray.push('...'),
 joinArrayToArrayPopPushJoin = joinArrayToArray.join(' '),
 productTitleExcerpt = joinArrayToArrayPopPushJoin;

 $('#products-carousel').find('.single-trending-list').find('h3').text(productTitleExcerpt);
```

```html
<ul class="ul-trending-list" id="products-carousel">
  <li>
    <div class="single-trending-list">
      <span>$90.00</span>
      <h3>Leather Clutch, Gray Distressed</h3>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="single-trending-list">
      <span>$91.00</span>
      <h3>Sori Yanagi Butterfly Y Wenge Stool</h3>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="single-trending-list">
      <span>$31.00</span>
      <h3>BOTTLIT Canister, 600ml</h3>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I've made a **SOLUTION** . Now I've used **each method** and also create a function and set 3 **arg** to pass **element**, **letter number**, **extension** optional. So now I can use it anywhere.

Here is [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Jim_Fahad/c56osLt6/)

And Here is the code you can see here.

```js
var originalCarouselH3 = $('#products-carousel').find('.single-trending-list').find('h3');

 function excerpt(excerptElement, number , more = "..."){
  excerptElement.each(function(){
  var productTitle = $(this).text(),
  productTitleExcerpt,
  toArray = productTitle.split("", number),
  joinArray = toArray.join(''),
  joinArrayToArray = joinArray.split(" "),
  joinArrayToArrayPop = joinArrayToArray.pop(),
  joinArrayToArrayPopPush = joinArrayToArray.push(more),
  joinArrayToArrayPopPushJoin = joinArrayToArray.join(' '),
  productTitleExcerpt = joinArrayToArrayPopPushJoin;

  if(productTitle.length > number){
   productTitle = productTitleExcerpt;
   $(this).text(productTitle);
  }
  });
 }

 excerpt(originalCarouselH3, 30);
```

```html
<ul class="ul-trending-list" id="products-carousel">
  <li>
    <div class="single-trending-list">
      <span>$90.00</span>
      <h3>Leather Clutch, Gray Distressed</h3>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="single-trending-list">
      <span>$91.00</span>
      <h3>Sori Yanagi Butterfly Y Wenge Stool</h3>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="single-trending-list">
      <span>$31.00</span>
      <h3>BOTTLIT Canister, 600ml</h3>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Why don't you add your solution as an answer below, instead of appending it to your question? :-)

Comment: Oh..I see. Let me redo

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is actually a plugin for jQuery called [Succinct](https://github.com/micjamking/Succinct) that truncates text. This plugin supports multi-line text. But if you do not want to include this plugin, and you only need to truncate text per-line, it easy to create one.

Here is the easiest way to do what you are trying to do, using jQuery.

```js
$('#products-carousel .single-trending-list h3').each(function() {
  $(this).text($(this).text().substr(0, 36) + '...');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="ul-trending-list" id="products-carousel">
  <li>
    <div class="single-trending-list">
      <span>$90.00</span>
      <h3>Leather Clutch, Gray Distressed</h3>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="single-trending-list">
      <span>$91.00</span>
      <h3>Sori Yanagi Butterfly Y Wenge Stool</h3>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="single-trending-list">
      <span>$31.00</span>
      <h3>BOTTLIT Canister, 600ml</h3>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

### But...

The correct way to do this would be the use CSS to truncate the text. This will leave the text unmodified but only displayed truncated.

```css
.single-trending-list h3 {
  width: 11em;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="ul-trending-list" id="products-carousel">
  <li>
    <div class="single-trending-list">
      <span>$90.00</span>
      <h3>Leather Clutch, Gray Distressed</h3>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="single-trending-list">
      <span>$91.00</span>
      <h3>Sori Yanagi Butterfly Y Wenge Stool</h3>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="single-trending-list">
      <span>$31.00</span>
      <h3>BOTTLIT Canister, 600ml</h3>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

---

### jQuery Plugins to the Rescue!

```js
(function($) {
  $.fn.truncate = function(length) {
    this.text(function(idx, txt) {
      return txt.length > length ? txt.substr(0, length) + '…' : txt;
    });
  }
  $.fn.truncateCss = function(width) {
    this.each(function() {
      $(this).css({
        width : width,
        whiteSpace: 'nowrap',
        overflow: 'hidden',
        textOverflow: 'ellipsis',
      });
    });
  }
} (jQuery));

// ======================================================================
// USE EITHER ONE
// ======================================================================
$('#products-carousel .single-trending-list h3').truncate(22);
//$('#products-carousel .single-trending-list h3').truncateCss('11em');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="ul-trending-list" id="products-carousel">
  <li>
    <div class="single-trending-list">
      <span>$90.00</span>
      <h3>Leather Clutch, Gray Distressed</h3>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="single-trending-list">
      <span>$91.00</span>
      <h3>Sori Yanagi Butterfly Y Wenge Stool</h3>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="single-trending-list">
      <span>$31.00</span>
      <h3>BOTTLIT Canister, 600ml</h3>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You beat me to it! Here's a codepen: http://codepen.io/vic3685/pen/dMGxNg - What you want to take away from this is the function each().

Comment: I'm not sure truncating with CSS is the correct way to go. Ellipsis only works with one line of text. If he's trying to limit the amount of text to, let's say, 3 lines instead of 4, CSS won't help. It might be better to do the truncating server-side if that's a possibility.

Comment: @vic3685: I mentioned the [Succinct plugin](https://github.com/micjamking/Succinct), which does truncate multi-line text. I will clarify.

Answer (score 5):

This question is already long solved, but I thought I would post my solution in the case it might help other digital journey ladies / men in search of making a snippet!

**I wanted to cut off the original string at a blank space**. In this instance, I found [lastIndexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/lastIndexOf) quite useful!

```
if (someString.length > EXCERPT_MAX_LENGTH) {
  excerpt = someString.substring(0, EXCERPT_MAX_LENGTH);
  excerpt = excerpt.substring(0, excerpt.lastIndexOf(' '));
  excerpt += '...';
}
```

Note that I append an [Ellipsis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsis) to the end of the resulting shorten string!

Answer (score 3):

Instead of finding all captions at the same time, loop through each h3 found and push the caption to an array.

```
var productTitle =[]; 
$('#products-carousel').find('.single-trending-list').find('h3').each(
  function() {
    productTitle.push($(this).text())
  }
)
```

The value of productTitle in the JSFiddle example given will be:

`["Leather Clutch, Gray Distressed", "Sori Yanagi Butterfly Y Wenge Stool", "BOTTLIT Canister, 600ml"]`

You can then loop through each value in the array with a for loop and do what you want with it.

Answer (score 3):

Try to use the `callBack` function of `.text()` to achieve what you want,

```
$('#products-carousel .single-trending-list h3').text(function(_, txt) {
  return txt.length > 36 ? txt.substr(0, 36) + "..." : txt;
});
```

### [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/8s3Lturh/5/)

Answer (score 0):

The shortest way to do that, I think is this.

```
$(".your-selector").each(function() { $(this).text($(this).text().substr(0, 140) + "..."); });
```

Note that "140" can be changed according to your desired length.